# How can I respond to negativity on this network?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking on this meta because it's the only site I have reputation for. Although I am happy to delete the question if it is off-topic. I recently tried to ask a question which led to this happening:

[image]

The top comment was by a user with 60k reputation which states:

> Look, nobody is forcing you to apply and get a job. You don't want to play by the rules, fine. Just don't whine here on this site. Nobody has time for that.

I recognize that people will be rude on the Internet and that is unavoidable, but I do not feel comfortable participating on this network (note: I am not saying the same for this site, people have been cordial on here) if my questions will be closed with rude comments. Yes, I know some of you will say "that comment is not rude, it is simply terse" or that "this question is a rant". I am not trying to rant, but keep myself composed as I did in the image above.

Instead of waiting for a moderator to swoop in and delete the comment, knowing my question would be closed anyways, I deleted my profile. I'm sure there could be a more constructive way of dealing with negative feedback: what is the proper etiquette for doing so on here?

Comment: [Here is a link to the question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83417/is-keyword-matching-an-acceptable-practice), although I doubt many people would be able to view it. Unfortunately I didn't save the question text.

Comment: FWIW I was in the middle of writing an *answer* to your question when you deleted it. Your question did sound like a rant with phrases like "dubious claim", "do I really want to work here", "time consuming", and so on. But after reading your comment, I decided to accept that you did not *intend* to rant. I even provided you feedback to tone down the language to get a serious answer, although I admit I did not do it diplomatically enough. I was planning to edit your question next after finishing my answer, but could not do it because the question got deleted.

Comment: Not sure if you can read this message, but I have now edited your question and voted to undelete it. If it does get undeleted, feel free to recreate your account and link the question to your account by asking a moderator. I may also continue with writing my answer. :)

Comment: The question being referenced has been reopened.

Comment: I saw this coming in a couple of my previous posts concerning rudeness...There are many users who do not understand how new posters think, and often respond to everyone as if they are seasoned veterans of the Workplace. It has caused some problems on this site, but hopefully can be resolved.

Answer (score 6):

Warm welcome to The Workplace! (although it was not quite warm)

**I have edited your now-deleted question and voted to undelete it.** If the question gets undeleted, feel free to recreate your account, and ask a moderator to link your question to your account.

Your description did sound like a rant against the hiring practice of shortlisting resumes based on keyword count. However, you commented that you were *not* ranting, which I accepted and suggested you to tone down the language to be taken more seriously.

I was also *writing an answer* and wanted to edit your question myself, but the question got deleted before I could complete my answer.

Now coming to your questions. **I agree that some of us, including me, tend to be a bit brusque in our comments**, but you should also know that we frequently get trolls here who post rants and nonsense questions. As a result, **our "troll detector" sometimes catches genuine posts**.

**The best approach to such perceived negativity is to respond positively.** If someone says you sound like ranting, respond with "no, I am not ranting" and explain why (which you did!). Engaging in a comment confrontation does not help.

**If things start getting seriously bad, flag the comment for moderator attention.** The moderators here do a fine job without bias (except when feminism and religion are involved, but I digress), they will delete the offensive comments and even lock the posts if needed, regardless of user's reputation. In fact, the more common complaint here is that the moderators delete *too many* comments. :-)

Comment: I think that could be edited down further to just state the issue and ask the question, dropping the  objections and simplifying to "this seems ridiculous; is it really true and if so how/should I try to make this work in my favor". Brevity  does increase odds of getting responses; pre-arguing for a particular outcome tends to decrease them.

Comment: I know the post is more verbose than it needs to be, but I felt that without enlisting those reasons and the rest of the explanation, the post once again sounds like whining. "This system sucks, but anyway, how do I make it work?" I decided to leave it in, so that it at least appears that OP has tried thinking about the problem, and isn't just complaining about a necessary nuisance.

Comment: @MaskedMan - You're definitely making a heroic effort fixing the post. I didn't want to even try, because I anticipated a lot of pain.  And a fair amount of time. You're going above and beyond.

Comment: The first question I think needs to be asked is "is this really the system". I have an unsupported feeling that this is starting from a false assumption.

Comment: We don't seem to be getting anywhere. Let the OP clean up after himself.

Comment: @MaskedMan the question has been un-deleted

Comment: @RichardU Thanks for letting me know. :)

Comment: I voted to reopen

Comment: I was in the middle of writing a *great* answer :), but unfortunately, I have lost the flow of thoughts now, I hope will regather it by the time the question gets reopened (if it does).